# Error when trying to encrypt

Tags: node.js, encryption

When I'm trying to create an encrypted text from a text using crypto(Node.JS) , I get a "Error: Must give cipher-type, key".

Code is as follows.

```
var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-256-cbc', userId);
var crypted = cipher.update(password, 'utf8', 'hex');
crypted += cipher.final('hex');
return crypted;
```

But when I'm testing it using mocha, it doesn't give any errors. In both times, the inputs are given correctly. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. I changed the userId in to userId.toString('binary') and now it works. Still not sure how the difference between mocha run and normal run happens.

```
var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-256-cbc', userId);
```

changed to

```
var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-256-cbc', userId.toString('binary'));
```

Comment: "Still not sure how the difference between mocha run and normal run happens." Me neither. Fixed the same problem for me though.